# ML function currying

Tags: functional-programming, sml, currying, smlnj, ml

Could someone please explain the concept of currying to me. I am primarily learning it because we are learning ML in my 'modern programming language' class for a functional language introduction.

In particular you can use this example:

```
    -fun g a = fn b => a+b;
      val g = fn: int -> int -> int
    -g 2 3;
      val it = 5 : int
```

I'm confused how these parameters are passed or how to even think about it in the first place.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you make the currying explicit, so it should be easier to understand.

If we read the function definition, it says (paraphrased): "Create a function `g`, which when given an `a` returns `fn b => a+b`."

That is, if we call `g 2`, we get back the function `fn b => 2+b`. As such, when we call `g 2 3`, we actually call `(g 2) 3`; that is we first get the function stated above back, and then use this function on the value `3`, yielding `5`.

Currying is simply the concept of making a function in several "stages", each taking an input and producing a new function. SML has syntactic sugar for this, making `g` equivalent to the following:

```
fun g a b = a + b;
```

Comment: The fully spelled-out version would look like this: `val g = fn a => fn b => a + b`. I find this useful because it shows that functions are values, and there is no special magic to the `fun` keyword.

Comment: @waldrumpus: Actually, `fun` is syntactic sugar for a `val rec`, not a `val`, though that isn't important in this case. :)

Comment: How does the 'environment' (I'm using SML/NJ) know what a is in fn b=> a+b know what a is in this case? Isn't that an unbound variable at that point. Maybe the confusion is the way I am reading it; should I be reading left to right or right to left?

Comment: @nickbonnet: It creates what is called a closure, which remembers the value of the `a`, in effect substituting it into the function, where `a` occurred.