# The difference between parentheses in curried function types

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

What's the different of those return type ??

```
val fn1 : int −> (int −> (int −> int))
val fn2: (int −> int) −> (int −> int)
```

This creates a function of type

```
int -> int -> int    meaning    int -> (int -> int)
```

is that right? They have the same meaning without bracket!

Answer (score 3):

The function type of `fn1` is, as you say, equivalent to `int -> int -> int -> int`.

When you have multiple [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906348/ml-function-currying) arguments like `fn1 a b c`, then `fn1 a` is a function of type `int -> int -> int`, and `fn1 a b` is a function of type `int -> int`. So `fn1` could also be seen as a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns an `int`. Adding the parentheses like `int -> (int -> (int -> int))` highlights that interpretation.

The function `fn2` is different: It takes a function of type `int -> int` as argument and returns another function of type `int -> int`.

Comment: to add, `fn2`'s type can also be written as `(int -> int) -> int -> int`, but the first parentheses cannot be gotten rid of

Answer (score 0):

Functions in SML take one argument and return one value. *End of story.*

Well, not quite.

When we need to pass multiple arguments to a function there are two ways to do this. You can either pass a tuple or record or some other aggregate data structure to the function. This is a single value, but it is composed of multiple pieces of data.

```
fun f (x, y) = x * 3 + y
```

Where currying comes from is that functions are values as well, and functions return a single value. That value can be a function. So we could write:

```
val f = fn x => fun y => x * 3 + y
```

That's tedious, so we can write it as:

```
fun f x y = x * 3 + y
```

This is very amenable to partial application: binding that function returned by applying one argument to `f` to a new name and then calling it on the remaining argument.

```
val g = f 3;
val h = g 1; (* 10 *)
```

A function like `f` could be given the type `int -> (int -> int)` because the describes what it does: given an `int` value return a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`. But `int -> int -> int` describes this equivalently.

Now, if you see `(int -> int) -> int`, that describes something different. That means the function takes a function as an argument and returns an `int`.

An example of a function that does that:

```
fun g f = 1 + f 5
```

Because that `int -> int` function represents one value passed in as an argument, the parentheses cannot be removed from the type signature `(int -> int) -> int`.